# Command for changing recorded python lines, so that the recording uses Cartesian coordinate system

Tags: python, abaqus

Abaqus records commands issued to it in .rec and .jnl files. When defining sets the geometry referencing is on default in the following format:

```
mdb.models['Model1'].rootAssembly.instances['n2'].vertices.getSequenceFromMask(('[#9a400000 #199 ]', ), ))
```

I would like the "[#9a400000 #199 ]" to instead use Cartesian coordinate system (as per example below). I know Abaqus can do it, but I cannot seem to find the command to make the switch.

Cartesian reference example:

```
mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['x'].Set(faces=
mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['x'].faces.findAt(((47.768792, 13.01765, 
493.344593), (-0.414654, -0.857575, 0.304346)),......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Abaqus will represent sequences written to the replay (.rpy), journal (.jnl), and recovery (.rec) files using a mask. This is a good default, because sequences can often become very large.

This default output format can be changed using the JournalOptions object. The full documentation is listed in the Abaqus Scripting Reference Guide under *Session Commands*.  The code to use a Cartesian coordinate format for geometry sequences, for example, should be:

```
from abaqusConstants import *
session.journalOptions.setValues(replayGeometry=COORDINATE,
                                 recoverGeometry=COORDINATE)
```

where `COORDINATE` is an abaqus constant from the `abaqusConstants` module.